# Analyze the stability of the solutions is:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$X_{t+1}=1-\frac{1}{X_{t} +a+1}$, if $0<a<1$

Comment: There is something wrong in your formula, as this does not constitute dynamical system. (It seem me it should be $X_{t+1}=1-\frac{1}{X_{t}+a+1}$).

Comment: you're right, I've already put the correct form

Comment: It seem to me the general solution is of form $X_{n}=1-\frac{1}{n+(n-1)*a-\frac{1}{X_{0}+a+1}}$ (for some initial $x_{0}$). So to analyze stability you should consider for which values $a$ and $X_{0}$ it converges, for which it not, and for which their is $\frac{something}{\infty}$ for some $n$.